How to debug KeyBindings
We have a very complicated setting, like WPF controls hosted inside WinForms controls hosted inside COM controls hosted inside Microsoft Access.
This works most of the time, but it always gives headaches when you want to fix a bug or want to add a feature.
But this setting is why I'm not always sure, where the focus sits and what layer catches key strokes.
Right now I'm supposed to add shortcuts to some functions in a (self made) menu. Since this is done with KeyBindings in other parts of our application, I wanted to go the same way.
So, just for testing I added a KeyBinding to the WPF control and bound it to an ICommand in the view model. When I run our application and snoop this control, I see my KeyBinding with the defined modifiers and key and with the ICommand it's bound to.
But when I press the defined shortcut, nothing happens, I also don't reach the break point in my code, so I guess the shortcut didn't get caught or is blocked or something like this.
Is there any way to check, whether a defined KeyBinding got active or not? Maybe an automatic log entry somewhere?

It is a standard failure mode when writing add-ins with WPF.  Set a breakpoint on an event handler you can activate, like a menu item's Click.  Look at the call stack when the breakpoint hits and verify that you see Application.Run().  With the common case that you don't and thus can't get shortcuts to work.  Only semi-decent workaround is to use ShowDialog() instead of Show() to display the window.

Since we only have WPF controls (hosted inside Microsoft Acces in the end), but no pure WPF application, I probably won't see any Application.Run() in the call stack?

When you say that it's inside Microsoft Access, is it an ActiveX ?

I'm not quite sure. There's a COM control inside an OCX file, which Microsoft Access references to. This COM control hosts something that can show WinForms stuff, and the WinForms stuff hosts something that can show WPF stuff.

Then you should be able to start a WPF application.

But there is no WPF application to start, just Microsoft Access hosting a few WPF controls.

The name WPF Application is misleading here. It's not an application. It's just a singleton that is responsible for a bunch of things (like resource resolution). You do want this singleton to be instantiated. I'm curious on how you manage your styles without it.

I don't have the source code of all these layers (COM control, WinForms control) so I can't check, whether an Appliation is really instantiated. But since we use styles and resources and stuff, there seems to be an instantiated Application.  Plus, KeyBindings work in other parts of our application (WPF as well), so I guess it should work in my case as well. That's why I look for a way to check, whether the error is before or after the KeyBinding I defined.
